# Use Stuff() Function to combine multiple rows

Tags: sql-server

I have read posts on the stuff () function and I believe it is the function I should be using for my query.

However, I need to take the example at this post further and add more columns, and include a sub query that pulls the reason text that matches my reason ID from another table. I have a table with a date, patientID, reason, otherNotes... I need to combine all the notes/reasons for each patient and each date into one column so that:

```
Date        patientID       reason .....other columns....
__________________________________________________________
12/26/2016   2              age
12/26/2016   2              location
12/27/2016   2              missing info
12/27/2016   2              age
```

becomes

```
Date        patientID       reason .....other columns....
__________________________________________________________
12/26/2016   2              age, location
12/27/2016   2              missing info, age
```

Here is what I started to create but it is giving me all the reasons for the patient not just the ones that belong to the date. In addition I don't know how to add to the query to pull the rest of my columns.

Please help me create a good strong query.

```
     SELECT distinct DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dateAdded), 0), 
            otherNote = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + (CASE WHEN eligibilityReason= 7 
            THEN otherNote ELSE Reasons.reason end) as reason 
            FROM Eligibility left Join Reasons on Reasons.reasonID = eligibilityReason 
            WHERE patientID=2 
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
            FROM Eligibility 
            GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, dateAdded), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate the sub-query with the outer query.

```
SELECT distinct 
      DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, eg.dateAdded), 0)
    , otherNote = STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + (CASE WHEN e.eligibilityReason= 7 
                                                THEN e.otherNote 
                                            ELSE r.reason 
                                        end) as reason 
                          FROM Eligibility e
                          left Join Reasons on r.reasonID = e.eligibilityReason 
                          where eg.patientID = e.patientID  --<-- Correlate
                          AND  eg.[Date] = e.[Date]         --<-- Correlate
                          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM Eligibility eg
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, eg.dateAdded), 0)
```

Comment: its still not allowing me to group by date! error is Column 'Eligibility.patientID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Column 'Eligibility.dateAdded' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Add PatientID to the Group By list, unless you want to group by only date and lump different patients together.

Comment: thanks, but i still get Column 'Eligibility.dateAdded' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.